# Is it possible to show user an error message if email was not sent - using PHP script

Tags: php, forms, validation, email, error-handling

I've built a simple contact form in `php`.  I was testing to see if my error message would display in the event of an unsuccessful attempt to send email.  I've left my `$emailTo` variable, which is passed to `mail()`,  blank in order to force the error message, but unfortunately it is not displaying.  The `$successMessage` displays regardless if `$emailTo` contains a valid email or not.

Is there a better way to test for a successfully sent email and display the `$error` message?

Code is as follows...

```
<?php

    $error = '';    
    if ($_POST) {

        if(!$_POST['email']) {
            $error.= 'The email address field is required.<br>';
        }

         if(!$_POST['subject']) {
            $error.= 'The subject field is required.<br>';
        }

         if(!$_POST['content']) {
            $error.= 'The message field is required.<br>';
        }

        //Validation for email (Check if it exsists and if its valid)
        if (($_POST['email']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
            $error .= '<p>The email address entered is invalid</p><br>';
        }

        //If there are errors...
        if($error != '') {
            $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><p><strong>Oh snap! There were error(s) in your form:</strong></p>'.$error. '</div>';

        //If there are no errors...`
        } else {
            $emailTo = '';  //!!!!!Left blank on purpose to test error message!!!!!
            $subject = $_POST['subject'];
            $content = $_POST['content'];
            $headers = "From: ".$_POST['email'];

            //If all fields are filled in, post successMessage to html
            if(mail($emailTo, $subject, $content, $headers)) {
                $successMessage = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><strong>Your message was sent, I\'ll get back to you soon!</strong></div>';

            //If email couldn't get through
            //!!!!!This is the message I cannot get to display!!!!
            } else {
                $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><strong><p>Oh dang! Your message couldn\'t be sent - please try again later.</strong><div>';
            }
        }  
    }



?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <h1>Contact me!</h1>


            <div id="error"><?php  echo $error.$successMessage; ?></div>

            <form method="post">
                <!--EMAIL ADDRESS-->
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email address:</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address">
                    <small class="text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                </fieldset>

                <!--SUBJECT-->
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="">
                </fieldset>

                <!--MESSAGE-->
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <label for="content">Your message:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="content" name="content" rows="3"></textarea>
                </fieldset>

                <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>

   <!-- jQuery first, then Bootstrap JS. -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vZ2WRJMwsjRMW/8U7i6PWi6AlO1L79snBrmgiDpgIWJ82z8eA5lenwvxbMV1PAh7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>

  </html>
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of concatenating, I prefer [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)() because it's more handy:

```
if (isset($_POST)) {

    if(empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $error = 'The email address field is required.<br>';
    }elseif(empty($_POST['subject'])) {
        $error = 'The subject field is required.<br>';
    }elseif(empty($_POST['content'])) {
        $error = 'The message field is required.<br>';
    }elseif (empty($_POST['email']) || filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === FALSE) {
        $error = '<p>The email address entered is invalid</p><br>';
    }else {
        $emailTo = '';  //!!!!!Left blank on purpose to test error message!!!!!
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $content = $_POST['content'];
        $headers = "From: ".$_POST['email'];

        //If all fields are filled in, post successMessage to html
        if(mail($emailTo, $subject, $content, $headers)) {
            $successMessage = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
         <strong>Your message was sent, I\'ll get back to you soon!</strong></div>';

        //If email couldn't get through
        //!!!!!This is the message I cannot get to display!!!!
        } else {
            $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> 
             <strong><p>Oh dang! Your message couldn\'t be sent - 
                      please try again later.</strong><div>';
        }
    }  
}
```

You can also check the success message and error message using `empty()`:

```
   if(!empty($error)){
         echo $error;
        }elseif(!empty($successMessage)){
            echo $successMessage;
        }else{}
    ; ?>
```

It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination.